# What is wrong with my do/while loop?

Tags: objective-c, while-loop, conditional-statements

the following code gives me an error of: "expected ';' before '{' token". can anyone see why?

```
do {
  r = rand() % numElements;
} while ([questionsShown containsObject:r] && myCount < numElements) {
  //code here…
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have two brackets after your while. Get rid of those. Plus place a semicolon.

```
do { 
r = rand() % numElements; 
// code should go here
} while ([questionsShown containsObject:r] && myCount < numElements);
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a do/while loop is so:

```
do {
    //code
} while (condition);

//more code
```

(Note the semicolon at the end).

Your code looks like:

```
do {
    r = rand() % numElements;
} while ([questionsShown containsObject:r] && myCount < numElements)

{
    //code here...
}
```

See how you're missing a semicolon?